# Работа с файлами С++

Tags: c++, файлы

Потребовалось поработать с файлами в С++. К моему удивлению, это оказалось не просто, в отличие от С#.

Требуется определить по пути, файл это или каталог. На MSDN нашёл как это делается, только их namespace-ы:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Collections;
```

у меня не канают: их просто не видно. Подскажите, что делать?

Обозначаю проблему: 
требуется кроссплатформенное решение для опроеделения - элемент является файлом или каталогом.

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает что эти namespace из C++/CLI, т.е. для .net. Или он и нужен ?

Comment: Отрицать не стану) Что же мне использовать?

Comment: Ну собственно изначально нужно определить :-) .net вам нужен или native

Comment: Если .net, то сильных отличий от C# не будет как раз таки. с native уже более шире вопрос.

Comment: Вообще программа должна быть как можно более кроссплатформенной, значит native.

Comment: По win платформе могу подсказать WinAPI использовать [GetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx) или [PathIsDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773621(VS.85).aspx), по кроссплатформенным решениям сказать не смогу сейчас, перешел давно на java :-) Раньше boost был актуален, сейчас не знаю.

Comment: Для кроссплатформенности посмотрите на Qt

Comment: На Qt нет особого желаения пока программировать). Ну значит костылить придётся)

Comment: У вас консольная программа?

Comment: Вообще да, она будет работать фоном как клиент-сервер и получать запросы от пользователей. Но подключаемый интерфейс всё-равно делать придётся.

Comment: Я просто хотел сказать, что если вам нужен кроссплатформенный gui, то вам в любом случае придется выбирать какую-то библиотеку. Может в ней будут средства для работы с файлами

Comment: *namespace* вам не требуется, вместо вам нужна или библиотека винды `#include <windows.h>` или стандартные библиотеки библиотеки `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Боюсь, что <stdio.h> мне не подойдёт. Мне не нужно ничего записывать в файл. Мне требуется определить файл это или каталог, если указанный путь существует, и занести элемент в Zip. Соответственно для каталога нужно будет заносить целую структуру.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А так не годится?

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

bool isDir(const char * name)
{
    struct stat st;
    return (stat(name,&st) == 0) && (S_IFDIR & st.st_mode);
};

bool isFile(const char * name)
{
    struct stat st;
    return (stat(name,&st) == 0) && (S_IFREG & st.st_mode);
};
```

Не знаю компилятора, где этого нет :)

Comment: Если это работает под Linux, то просто идеально)

Comment: Будет работать, только константы, скорее всего, будут без подчерков впереди. Да, я проверил - работает и в Linux (Mint), и в Windows.

Comment: Как же красиво)

Answer (score 0):

1. Простой сишный (не плюсовый) путь: [man stat](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fstat&category=2) (если в Windows с чем-то из этого проблемы - там есть [другие](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx)). Можно попробовать просто открыть как каталог и проанализировать результат (`ENOTDIR`, см. [man opendir](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=opendir&category=3&russian=0), [opendir в Windows](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.html)).
2. Из именно плюсовых (но зачем, если есть п.1?) приходит в голову разве что [is_directory()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#is_directory) (бустовая Filesystem Library).

Comment: dirent.h надо отдельно подключать?

Comment: Конечно же. Но боязнь заголовочных файлов не имеет под собой никаких оснований :) Это просто объявления прототипов используемых функций. Подключите хоть весь системный каталог include, ничего страшного не произойдёт. Ну разве что скорость сборки немного упадёт.

Comment: Не, я не об этом, просто её ещё надо скачать))

Comment: @Сергей, `dirent.h`, `sys/stat.h` и т.д. - часть стандартной сишной библиотеки, должны входить по умолчанию в дистрибутив любого компилятора.

Comment: sys\stat.h видит, а dirent.h нет почему-то.

Comment: @Сергей а, так под Windows его и нет, надо исходник по ссылке качать, да. Но он и не нужен, если не собираетесь использовать opendir/readdir/closedir, для проверки только на is_directory хватит и stat.